# Is there any deep reason because LCD display have always an even number of rows and columns?

Tags: 3d

Is there any deep reason because LCD display have always an even number of rows and columns ?

Maybe rasterization issues, raytracing issues, or other explanations ....

If I have a row or a column that is in the exact center of the panel, what is the problem ?